# Django-haystack & solr : Increase the number of results

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I have this function :

```
def search_books(request):
    search_text = request.POST.get('search_text')
    if search_text:
        books = SearchQuerySet().filter(content=search_text).filter(quantite__gte=0)

    else:
        books = []
    return render_to_response("search/search.html", {'books': books})
```

By default it returns only 20 results, is there a way to increase that number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is specified by the [**`HAYSTACK_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE`** setting [readthedocs.io]](https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/master/settings.html#haystack-search-results-per-page). You can specify a different number in the `settings.py` file:

```
# settings.py

# …

HAYSTACK_SEARCH_RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 50

# …
```